# What is ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level string error?

Tags: oracle, progress-4gl, openedge

I am getting this error while executing some query with progress 4GL on oracle db. Anybody have any information about this. I am using dynamic query to access 2 tables.

For each table1 no-lock where table1.field1 = "xyz",
   First table2 no-lock where table2.field1 = 123  and table2.field2.

Here table2.field2 is logical.
When I use it as static query, I get records.
But when I use dynamic query using query prepare, there is no error in query prepare and query open,
but when I use query_handle:get-first, I am getting oracle error number 604

Comment: you forgot to post the `query` !!

Comment: ORA-00604 means there was no real error in your SQL but some error in SQL that the Oracle DBMS generated and ran in order to satisfy your query, either while parsing or while executing.

Comment: @nileshpharate Might be a trigger, a VPD, ... You need to supply a *lot* more information (DDL statements for the schema, example data, the query you're running etc.)